# How to implement bi-directional LSTM network in pybrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain, lstm

I am trying to implement a bidirectional LSTM network in pybrain. Anyone has any sample code as an example?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's perfectly documented inside the test code.
See [here](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/tests/unittests/structure/networks/test_bidirectional_network.py) on github.

> Build a bi-directional Network for sequences (each sample a single
> value) of length 20:
>
> ```
> >>> n = BidirectionalNetwork(seqlen=20, inputsize=1, 
>                              hiddensize=5, symmetric=False)
> ```
>
> It should have 2x1x5 + 2x1x5 + 2x5x5 = 70 weights
>
> ```
> >>> n.paramdim
> 70
> ```
>
> Now let's build a symmetric network:
>
> ```
> >>> n = BidirectionalNetwork(seqlen=12, inputsize=2, 
>                              hiddensize=3, symmetric=True)
> >>> n.indim
> 24
> ```
>
> It should have 1x2x3 + 1x1x3 + 1x3x3 = 18 weights
>
> ```
> >>> n.paramdim
> 18
> ```
>
> A forward pass:
>
> ```
> >>> from numpy import ones
> >>> r = n.activate(ones(24))
> >>> len(r)
> 12
> ```
>
> The result should be symmetric (although the weights are random)
>
> ```
> >>> r[0]-r[-1]
> 0.0
> ```
>
> Check its gradient:
>
> ```
> >>> from pybrain.tests import gradientCheck
> >>> gradientCheck(n)
> Perfect gradient
> True
> ```